# shiny observe symbol °

Tags: r, shiny, paste, symbols

in my shiny app, I am using `observe` function and `updateTextInput`, it works fine, the only issue is when I try to `paste` a "°" symbol as a new default value for the `updateTextInput`. the code is like this:

```
observe({
   hodnotaY <- if (input$test == "Viscosity 135") {
   hodnotaY <- "[mPa*s]"
   }
   if (input$test == "Tcrit OB") {
     hodnotaY <- "[°C]"
   }

   updateTextInput(session, "ylabel_text_box_id", value = paste("", hodnotaY))
 })
```

if I leave out the ° symbol, like this: `hodnotaY <- "[C]"`, it works. The error message says:

```
Warning: Error in sourceUTF8: Error sourcing C:\Users\blasc\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpgJLnOJ\file84c2f09699e
  [No stack trace available]
Error in sourceUTF8(serverR, envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())) : 
  Error sourcing C:\Users\blasc\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpgJLnOJ\file84c2f09699e
```

As I am by no means a programmer I would be glad for any push in a right direction on how to solve it.

Comment: It works for me!

Comment: Well, for me there is still the same error, but thanks, now I know not to look for the error in the code but in the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies for not being too experienced with R myself, but I suspect you are trying to put a UTF-8 character into a non-UTF-8 variable. Does putting this before that line help?

```r
Encoding(hodnotaY) <- "UTF-8"
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but not really. But I believe you are correct that the error is not in the code itself but in the encoding. Even when I try to put the symbol anywhere in the code,  p.e.: textInput('just_test', label = 'test', value = "°C"),
it does not even load the app, just the blank screen with: ERROR: Error sourcing C:\Users\blasc\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpgJLnOJ\file84c4996185d